What lucene analyzer can be used to handle English, Arabic, Russian, Chinese, Thai, and Japanese text?
Which lucene analyzer can be used to handle English, Arabic, Russian, Chinese, Thai, and Japanese languages text properly? It should be able to handle English, Arabic, Russian, Chinese, Thai, and Japanese languages
I was using "standard.lucene," but I am facing trouble with the Japanese character "上武." Although the data exists, but no data is found.
Also, when using a wildcard for Japanese, no data is found.
Code
enter image description here
Text
"text": "高田工業株式会社泉崎",
Azure Search Service Toke
"tokens": [
    {
        "token": "高田",
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 2,
        "position": 0
    },
    {
        "token": "工業",
        "startOffset": 2,
        "endOffset": 4,
        "position": 1
    },
    {
        "token": "株式",
        "startOffset": 4,
        "endOffset": 6,
        "position": 2
    },
    {
        "token": "会社",
        "startOffset": 6,
        "endOffset": 8,
        "position": 3
    },
    {
        "token": "泉崎",
        "startOffset": 8,
        "endOffset": 10,
        "position": 4
    }
]

    public async Task<Azure.Pageable<SearchResult<T>>> SearchAsync<T>(string searchString, SearchOptions searchOptions, string indexName)
    {
        string? searchServiceEndPoint = Convert.ToString(_configuration["AzureSearch:BaseUrl"]);
        string? queryApiKey = Convert.ToString(_configuration["AzureSearch:Key"]);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchServiceEndPoint) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryApiKey))
        {
            SearchClient searchClient = new SearchClient(new Uri(searchServiceEndPoint), indexName, new AzureKeyCredential(queryApiKey));
            var searchResult = await searchClient.SearchAsync<T>(searchString, searchOptions);
            return searchResult.Value.GetResults();

        }
        else
            return default;//Pageable<SearchResult<T>>.FromPages(new List<Page<SearchResult<T>>>().AsEnumerable());
    }


To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

multi language support for same field.
I am trying to see possible solutions to deal with multi-language search functionality using Azure Cognitive Search.

@mehboob baloch do you want multi-language search functionality using Azure Cognitive Search with code like python ,c#, js etc

@Sampath yes i need to achieve multi-language functionality using Azure Cognitive Search with code like c# with "standard.lucene" Analyzer. i can't perform searching for Japanese. i have column customer name which contain multi-language characters.

@mehboobbaloch please add the sample code you tried in the above question

"text": "高田工業　高田薫",
"analyzer": "ja.microsoft"
"tokens": [
{
"token": "高田"
},
{
"token": "工業"
},
{
"token": "高田"
},
{
"token": "薫"
}
]
when search link "高田工業株式会社泉崎" no response return
if search like "高田 工業 株式 会社 泉崎" return response
but Japanese don't have space

@mehboobbaloch can you give code in text form

@Sampath can you understand issue

create separate field with Text Translation cognitive skill and perform query on that field.

The LexicalAnalyzerName struct in the Azure.Search.Documents.Indexes.Models namespace defines the names of all text analyzers supported by the Azure search engine. This struct includes a wide range of analyzers for different languages,  by both Lucene and Microsoft.
According to this MSDOC , for Japanese text use the JaLucene analyzer.
var definition = new SearchIndex("japanese-index", searchFields)
{
    Fields = new List<SearchField>
    {
        new SearchField("id", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsKey = true, IsSearchable = true, IsFilterable = true },
        new SearchField("Description_ja", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsSearchable = true, AnalyzerName = LexicalAnalyzerName.JaLucene }
    }
};

For English:
The below   Azure Cognitive Search  code with a .NET  supports multilingual search(en, ar, ru, zh, th, ja) using specific Lucene analyzers.
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AzureSearchService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task<Azure.Pageable<SearchResult<Document>>> SearchAsync(string searchString, SearchOptions searchOptions, string indexName)
    {
        string searchServiceEndPoint = _configuration["AzureSearch:BaseUrl"];
        string queryApiKey = _configuration["AzureSearch:Key"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchServiceEndPoint) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryApiKey))
        {
            SearchClient searchClient = new SearchClient(new Uri(searchServiceEndPoint), indexName, new AzureKeyCredential(queryApiKey));
            var searchResult = await searchClient.SearchAsync<Document>(searchString, searchOptions);
            return searchResult.Value.GetResults();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(" API key is missing.");
        }
    }

    public async Task CreateIndexAsync()
    {
        string searchServiceEndPoint = _configuration["AzureSearch:BaseUrl"];
        string adminApiKey = _configuration["AzureSearch:AdminKey"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchServiceEndPoint) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adminApiKey))
        {
            SearchIndexClient indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(new Uri(searchServiceEndPoint), new AzureKeyCredential(adminApiKey));

            var fieldBuilder = new FieldBuilder();
            var searchFields = fieldBuilder.Build(typeof(Document));

            var definition = new SearchIndex("multi-language-index", searchFields)
            {
                Fields = new List<SearchField>
                {
                    new SearchField("id", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsKey = true, IsSearchable = true, IsFilterable = true },
                    new SearchField("Description_en", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsSearchable = true, AnalyzerName = LexicalAnalyzerName.EnLucene },
                    new SearchField("Description_ar", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsSearchable = true, AnalyzerName = LexicalAnalyzerName.ArLucene },
                    new SearchField("Description_ru", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsSearchable = true, AnalyzerName = LexicalAnalyzerName.RuLucene },
                    new SearchField("Description_zh", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsSearchable = true, AnalyzerName = LexicalAnalyzerName.ZhHansLucene },
                    new SearchField("Description_th", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsSearchable = true, AnalyzerName = LexicalAnalyzerName.ThLucene },
                    new SearchField("Description_ja", SearchFieldDataType.String) { IsSearchable = true, AnalyzerName = LexicalAnalyzerName.JaLucene }
                }
            };

            await indexClient.CreateOrUpdateIndexAsync(definition);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(" API key is missing.");
        }
    }

    public async Task UploadDocumentsAsync()
    {
        string searchServiceEndPoint = _configuration["AzureSearch:BaseUrl"];
        string adminApiKey = _configuration["AzureSearch:AdminKey"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchServiceEndPoint) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adminApiKey))
        {
            SearchClient searchClient = new SearchClient(new Uri(searchServiceEndPoint), "multi-language-index", new AzureKeyCredential(adminApiKey));

            var documents = new[]
            {
                new Document { Id = "1", Description_en = "This is an English text.", Description_ar = "هذا نص عربي.", Description_ru = "Это русский текст.", Description_zh = "这是中文文本。", Description_th = "นี่คือข้อความภาษาไทย", Description_ja = "これは日本語のテキストです。" }
            };

            await searchClient.UploadDocumentsAsync(documents);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("API key is missing.");
        }
    }
}

public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string? Description_en { get; set; }
    public string? Description_ar { get; set; }
    public string? Description_ru { get; set; }
    public string? Description_zh { get; set; }
    public string? Description_th { get; set; }
    public string? Description_ja { get; set; }
}
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        IConfiguration configuration = builder.Build();
        var searchService = new AzureSearchService(configuration);

        // Create index
        await searchService.CreateIndexAsync();

        // Upload sample documents
        await searchService.UploadDocumentsAsync();

        // Search example
        var searchOptions = new SearchOptions
        {
            Filter = null,
            OrderBy = { "Description_en" },
            Select = { "Description_en", "Description_ar", "Description_ru", "Description_zh", "Description_th", "Description_ja" }
        };

        var searchResults = await searchService.SearchAsync("text", searchOptions, "multi-language-index");
used
        foreach (var result in searchResults)
        {
         Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.WriteLine($"Found document with English description: {result.Document.Description_en}");
        }


for Japanese:
var searchOptions = new SearchOptions
{
    Filter = null,
    OrderBy = { "Description_ja" },
    Select = { "Description_ja" }
};

var searchResults = await searchService.SearchAsync("これは日本語のテキストです", searchOptions, "multi-language-index");



